# Regex to remove string after last number?

Tags: javascript, regex

There are a lot of regex out there but I couldn't find the solution to my specific problem.

Consider these strings:

```
my street 13a
mystreet 3 B
my street karlos 15A
```

How can I return those:

```
my street 13
mystreet 3
my street karlos 15
```

`\d+[a-z,A-Z]` matches the case "13A, 13a" and `\d+ [a-z,A-Z]` matches it with whitespaces. After this I would just use this:

```
myCutStr = myOriginalString.match(/\d+[a-z,A-Z]/g);
myNewStr = myCutStr.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
myOriginalString.replace(myCutStr, myNewStr);
```

But can I somehow combine `\d+[a-z,A-Z]` and ignore white spaces in that regEx? So that this one `\d+[a-z,A-Z]` will match all of my kind even with whitespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single replace would be enough. That is, replace all the non-digit characters present at the last with an empty string.

```
string.replace(/\D+$/g, '');
```

OR

```
string.replace(/(\d)\D+$/g, '$1');
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kP3nM8/2)

Comment: Hey, thank you! But what is the difference between the first and the second?

Comment: first will remove all the non-digit characters present at the last, it won't care about the previous character. That is, it would remove the whole string if the input is `foo bar`. But the second one would remove all the non-digit chars at the last of a string only if the string contain a digit char at the start or at the middle.

Comment: Either I am doing something wrong, or the second one will also remove the last digit in the string. The first one seems to work, though

Comment: that's why i used `$1` in the replacement part. `$1` refers to chars which are present inside the group index 1.